# Expected value of two dependent variables is still a product of expectations

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, correlation

For independent variables we have $E[XY]=E[X]E[Y]$. Now, since I could not find a statement that the converse is also true, I suspect that there are examples of dependent variables where this relation still holds. Could anybody here give me an example?- I am somewhat interested in how this could look like.

Comment: Because the converse is false. I am sure google gives a counter example.

Comment: http://www.math.utah.edu/~davar/math5010/S07/Notes/Lec16.pdf here page 2

Comment: Correlation is linear relationship, independence is a lot more. The pictures on the wiki page illustrates this pretty well. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_and_dependence

Answer (score 12, accepted):

By definition, two random variables $X$ and $Y$ satisfy your equation if and only if their [covariance](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance) is zero.  Thus, any pair of dependent random variables with zero covariance give the counterexample you're looking for.

For instance, let $X$ be uniformly distributed between $-1$ and $1$, and let $Y = X^2$.  Then $$\mathrm E[XY] = \mathrm E[X^3] = 0 = \mathrm E[X] = \mathrm E[X]\mathrm E[Y],$$ even though $X$ and $Y$ are obviously not independent.

Comment: what I don't get is why you do not just refer to $X$ and $Y=X$? Why do you pick the "more complicated example" $X$ and $Y=X^2$=

Comment: @Lipschitz: Because if $Y = X$, then ${\rm E}[XY] = {\rm E}[X^2] = \frac12 \int_{-1}^1 x^2 \,dx = \frac13 \ne 0 = {\rm E}[X]{\rm E}[Y]$.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose that $(X,Y)$ is uniformly distributed on the unit disc.
In calculating
expectations $E[X]$, $E[Y]$, and $E[XY]$, it is best to convert the
double integrals over the unit disc (usually
set up in  rectangular coordinates) to polar coordinates and note that
$$\begin{align}
\int_0^{2\pi} cos\, \theta\, \mathrm d\theta = 0 &\Rightarrow E[X] = 0,\\
\int_0^{2\pi} sin\, \theta\, \mathrm d\theta = 0 &\Rightarrow E[Y] = 0,\\
\int_0^{2\pi} cos\,\theta\, \sin\,\theta\, \mathrm d\theta = 0 
&\Rightarrow E[XY] = 0.
\end{align}$$
Thus, $E[XY] = E[X]E[Y]$ for these random variables.  However, notice
that although $Y$ can take on all values in
$(-1,+1)$, if we know that
 $X = x, -1 < x < 1$, then $Y$ is necessarily restricted
to $\left(-\sqrt{1-x^2}, +\sqrt{1-x^2}\right) \subset (-1,1)$
which shows that $X$ and $Y$  are *dependent* random variables.